# I want to add an external library to jdk 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, xmpp, openfire, smack

I want to add an external library
I am using eclipse IDE and I followed the following procedure of clicking the preferences - > Java - > Installed JREs - > Edit - > add External JARs and after adding the Library I want, 
which is smack, but when I try to import one of the class from the new added library I am getting an error :

Access restriction: The type Connection is not accessible due to restriction on required library E:\Development Tools\Today\XMPP Project\smack_3_3_0\smack_3_3_0\smack.jar

I am tryiig to use the XMPP protocol for my application but I need the smack library to enable me implement XMPP.

Sorry for my ignorance Iam a newbie to smack and  XMPP, any help rendered Will be highly appreciated thank you very much thanks!

Comment: How do I navigate after that? Thank you by the way!

Comment: Just added how to do it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it.

- Open Eclipse, click on the name of your project on the left hand side
  pane called `"Package Explorer"`.
- Click `Project` on the menu-bar.
- Click `Properties`.
- Select `Java Build Path`.
- Click the `Libraries` tab.
- Click `Add External JARs`.
- Go to the directory where you downloaded the JAR and add it.

Comment: @thwildfire You're very welcome. Just accept the answer if it helped so it can help others as well.

Comment: dont mention hey have you worked with xmpp server before..I dont know if this the right approach but I have been trying set everythin up.

Comment: @thwildfire I haven't. Sorry about that.